# Avoiding eval when building radio buttons in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here, I am building database driven radio buttons. I wanted to know if there is a way I can avoid eval and see checked is true or not !Thanks,

Index Controller

```
 columns = Model.column_names
```

View in haml

```
- columns.each do |cols|
      - check = "c[0].#{cols}==1? true : false" // checking value here
      - negcheck = "c[0].#{cols}==0? true : false"// checking value here    
      - pluckid = "c[0].id"
      - id = eval(pluckid)
      %tbody
         %td #{cols}
         %td
          = label_tag 'On'
          = radio_button_tag("ABC",1,checked = eval(check), options = {})
          = label_tag 'Off'
          = radio_button_tag("xyz",0,checked = eval(negcheck), options = {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[]` method to access the value.

```
- columns.each do |cols|
      - check = c[0][cols] == 1
      - negcheck = c[0][cols] == 0
      - id = c[0].id
      %tbody
         %td #{cols}
         %td
          = label_tag 'On'
          = radio_button_tag("ABC", 1, checked = check, options = {})
          = label_tag 'Off'
          = radio_button_tag("xyz", 0, checked = negcheck, options = {})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval("c[0].#{cols}==1? true : false")
```

can be written as

```
c[0].send(cols) == 1
```